# How to replicate the internet connection when a XP Workstation is Virtualized?

Tags: windows-xp, vmware-esxi, internet, dsl, serial

Hi here is the issue for me;

We have a Workstation A which is connected to our Server B ; this workstation's sole puspose is to work as a terminal server for the outside vendor to login to the server and give support(fix any issues) ; The workstation is connected to external internet via DSL modem/router(via ethernet cable) and the connection between the server and workstation is a SERIAL CABLE(i know its a bad idea) ;

The probelm now is we virtualised workstation onto ESXi 5.1 ; my problem is how to replicate that internet connection to make it work as well as how to replicate the serial cable connection on the inner side?

please do let me know if any questions or clarifications required.
Please provide te alternate solutions too if possible; if this setup doesnt work we need to return back to physical XP workstation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take this opportunity to reevaluate your whole configuration.

Keep the workstation internal. Don't plug it directly into the Internet, and don't rig it so another box via serial. Configure it like any other box on your LAN. Just use a VPN like everyone else in the world that has to grant remote access. You put ACLs on your VPN termination point so that contractors/vendors/whatever can only get to this specific workstation.

As for how to grant access to the app on the server - if it's modern and supports serial, it probably supports SSH (or at least Telnet, right?) just use those.

Comment: Actually the external vendor uses telnet to connect to the workstation.

Comment: All the more reason to have them VPN first. Telnet sends all traffic in plain text, including credentials. I wouldn't be surprised if your machine has already been compromised.